# Spring bean getting confused

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a spring web app A and a library B. B has its one config file. When using the B library in App i am creating new beans instead of autowiring. but still seeing that the beans initialized in library are over writing the initialization i did  in App.

Here is a dummy config file to explain clearly:

**AConfig.java**

```
public class AConfig{

 @Bean 
public Info info(){
Info i =  new Info("A");
return i;
}

@Bean
public A a(){
A a = new A();
a.setInfo(info());
a.setB(b());
return A;
}

@Bean
public B b(){
B b = new B();
b.setInfo(info());
return b;
}

}
```

**BConfig.java**

```
public class BConfig(){

@Bean
public Info info(){
Info i = new Info("B);
}

@Bean

public B b(){

B b = new B();
b.setInfo(info());
return b;
}
}
```

Aconfig.java and BConfig.java both have info() methods to generate info bean. I am not having BConfig.java file in A project. i am not doing any autowiring. I am expecting that in projectA i must see the info bean to have String A but i am seeing string B. Some how the when creating Bean A the method info() of Bconfig.java is getting called instead of the info method from Aconfig.java.

Can someone explain why this is happening.

**EDIT**

In my spring log file i saw this line:

```
Overriding bean definition for bean 'Info': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=AConfig; factoryMethodName=info; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/configs/AConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=BConfig; factoryMethodName=info; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/configs/BConfig.class]]
```

feels like the bean i initialized in AConfig is being overwritten by BCOnfig.java but not sure why is spring overwriting.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is expected, this is because you have two beans with the exact same name `info` and the one defined later(in A) is the one which gets created at runtime. The behavior is same as what would have happened with the beans defined using xml.

How this happens is best explained by understanding the internals of Spring `@Configuration` which is explained with the Spring documentation here - http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-further-information-java-config. In short, even if you call `info()` method directly in `AConfig`, it is not actually invoking the method on the real `AConfig` instance, instead it is invoked on a proxy, which has the logic to make sure that the correct bean instance is returned.

Comment: Thanks. i am surprised to see this behaviour. Now how can i stop this overriding. I want the info bean defined in the Aconfig.java to be loaded in the App instead of the one from BConfig.java.

Comment: @javaMan you could add names to your beans in `AConfig` like `@Bean(name = "infoBean")` and then use `@Qualifier("infoBean")` when autowiring dependencies. See [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) for examples.